# Expose data from JSON file to Prometheus

Tags: prometheus

Is there any way to expose data from JSON file to Prometheus, so later it can be visualized in Grafana?

Comment: No, unless you write an exporter that reads the JSON and converts it to Prometheus format.

Comment: Would you mind sharing an example, or where i can find any exporter that reads the JSON and converts it to Prometheus format ?

Comment: There is a [JSON exporter](https://github.com/prometheus-community/json_exporter), check if it fits your needs. As for the examples. you can find them in Prometheus client libraries. Here's for example [the python library](https://github.com/prometheus/client_python).

Answer (score 0):

If you need importing historical data in JSON format into Prometheus, then you need converting this data to Prometheus remote_write format and then pushing it to`/api/v1/write` handler. See [these docs](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/storage/#overview).

Another option is to import the data to Prometheus-compatible system, so it could be queried later with PromQL in Grafana. See, for example, [how to import data in various formats into VictoriaMetrics](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/#how-to-import-time-series-data). (I'm the author of VictoriaMetrics).